# Apache redirection rules for wordpress sites

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd

I want to redirect `http://www.example.com/findyourname/` to `http://www.newexample.com./findyourname/`

`http://www.example.com` is a `wordpress` site , so when accessing `http://www.example.com/findyourname/` it fetches various pages as per log file

```
    "GET /wp-content/uploads/2017/09/green.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.example.com/findyourname/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" 518 "-" "Cookies:-" -
    "GET /wp-content/uploads/2017/09/example-banner-template_11974.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.example.com/findyourname/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0" 445 "-" "Cookies:-" -
    "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/05/example-logo-black.png HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://www.example.com/findyourname/" 
    ........
    ........
```

I wrote the below rules in `.htaccess` but I think this is not going to work .

```
    RewriteRule ^/findyourrep/  http://www.newexample.com/findyourname/ [NC,R=302,L]
```

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/findyourrep/  http://www.newexample.com/findyourname/ [NC,R=302,L]
> ```

In `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not have a slash prefix, so the regex should be `^findyourrep/` instead. The pattern `^/findyourrep/` will simply fail to match.

You also need to make sure this redirect goes *before* the WordPress front-controller, near the top of the `.htaccess` file.

Also note that the pattern `^findyourrep/` matches any URL that *starts* `/findyourrep/`, not just that single URL - is that the intention? Everything is then redirected to a single URL at the new host.

Providing `example.com` and `newexample.com` don't point to the same place, then that should be all that's required.